# File and Scanner objects for opening and reading data in Java

Tags: java, file-io, io, java.util.scanner, file-read

My textbook states the following:

*You can also use the `Scanner` class to read input from a file. Instead of passing `System.in` to the `Scanner` class constructor, you pass a reference to a `File` object. Here is an example:*

```
File myFile = new File("Customers.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
```

*The first statement creates an instance of the `File` class. The `File` class is in the Java API, and is used to represent a file. Notice that we have passed the string "`Customers.txt`" to the constructor. This creates a `File` object that represents the file "`Customers.txt`."*

*In the second statement, we pass a reference to this `File` object as an argument to the `Scanner` class constructor. This creates a `Scanner` object that uses the file "`Customers.txt`" as its source of input.*

My question: I am unable to understand why do we need a `File` object? Can't we write the above code just as below to read files?

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner("Customers.txt");
```

If Java needs a `File` object and a `Scanner` object, how is it exactly working behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `File` object  to the Scanner constructor to invoke [Scanner(File source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-) constructor and not [Scanner(String source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) constructor. In case you use the string `"Customers.txt"` as the argument the constructor with the string as argument will be used and it will produce *values scanned from the specified string* as explained in the documentation and not from the file as you want.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe is happening here is that the scanner class requires you to enter a primitive data type(aka String, int, etc.) and not a path.

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner("Customers.txt");
```

If you write the above code and display it, it will just be blank since the scanner class cannot understand your parameter. On the other hand, the class File takes in a path as a parameter and creates a file object that can be used as a parameter for the Scanner class. Hence why you have to create a file object before using the scanner class.